# How secure is JAR files or exe files from a Java program?

Tags: java

This is more just a general thought and speculation from my side, being a student of Computer science. 
Lets set the scene: 
Lets assume that I have created a wonderful application in Java that I plan on selling in the future. The java application has a complex structure and uses connections to a database using JDBC etc to connect to the DB, get the information from some table in the DB and then work with that data. 
To be able to connect the Java program to the DB i have to give the program some information of the DB such as the link, username to the DB and its password. 
My DB holds alot of information that I do not want others to see without authority. 
But these informations are clearly visible in the java code i created. How sure can I be that no one can access this information after the app has been compiled into a JAR file or a .EXE file?

This might be a dumb question, but I'm just curious.

Thanks

Comment: Zero to none. It's not jars (or) some other obfuscators. Legal agreements you have with your clients are the only binds you can enforce, other than that it is very easy to read what you have coded.

Comment: There's no way to get around reverse engineering in distributed, native applications. This is why web based solutions are much nicer!

Comment: JARs are very easy to decompile, exes can also be decompiled (albeit less effectively). This is why you should never trust the client

Comment: @christopherYeah, because web sites never get hacked ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compile the user & password values into your Java application.  Write your application with the ability to read those values from an external properties file.  Then it's your customers' responsibility to restrict access to *that* file so only trusted users can read or alter it.

Comment: That sounds good to, but really if a hacker can access the main Jar file then he could also get the external properties file. But I guess you are right when saying that the Java code is atleast safe and that the customer needs to take care of his own DB username and password.

Great answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Security concerns aside, configuration such as DB connection strings, usernames and passwords is not part of the shipped application but an installation specific setup. All the application needs to do, is to expose a simple way for the end users to spell out these settings (e.g. property files, xml, etc...).

With this approach, it is the users responsibility to secure usernames and passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't.  If it's in the jar or exe, it will be visible.  Your best bet is to encrypt the compiled files.

Comment: Yea, but then the decryption keys would be visible in the source code. I was going to suggest storing the usernames and passwords as byte arrays in the source code and running them through a simple shifting algorithm to obfuscate them. Still, anyone determined will be able to get to them, but it will be much less obvious what is going on in the code.

Comment: Yeah exactly, encryption just makes it more difficult

Comment: @user1274820 Yes, but part of your applications launch process could be requesting an appropriate key from the server

Comment: Right, but then what is to stop someone from running wireshark and using that key to log in? Maybe write a page on the server that will handle database requests and only allow certain requests or whatever? I would let the server handle the security and create adatabase for each client or whatever needs to be done - but of course, I can only speculate on what is in there

Answer (score 0):

There is really no possible way to prevent someone from decompiling your code back to something akin to its original state. You could make it more difficult, but if someone is determined, they can get it back to code form. As such the correct response is to not put any sensitive information into your java code. Put it somewhere else.

In this case, you might consider moving the information you want to client to access in your DB to a different DB, that doesn't contain sensitive information. Alternatively, if your database software allows it, create a new user on the DB, that only has access to the data the client will view, and use that login in your java program.

EDIT: mysql users

To create a new user in mysql run the following command:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

if you want the same user to be accessibble from any host replace `hostname` with `%`

This user is created with no permissions by default, so now onto adding permissions. Here is an example

```
GRANT [permission_level] ON database.table TO 'username'@'hostname';
```

Replace the table name with `*` to specify every table in the database.

for a full explanation of the syntax of these options look here: [CREATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html), [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

This should help you restrict who can access what in your mysql database.

Comment: This is sad information haha, but I guess there is nothing we can do at the moment. Does other programming languages offer more security on this part?

Also I was wondering if there is a way to authenticate the user and then give more rights to him if using MySQL for example

Comment: @HassanNazar I have yet to learn about any programming language that offers the security you require. In fact, I doubt it would even be possibble. This is due to the fact that a file must exist in usable binary form, which can always be reverse engineered to at least some extent by a determined individual. as to mySQL users, edit something in in a minute. I'm only passingly familiar with mysql, but I'm fairly sure that you can have multiple users with different permissions.

Comment: wonderful :), now a question arises as to how I will be able to change the permissions. Do I have the ability to check wether a login to the DB was established from the MySQL interface and automatically grant access? Or does this have to be implemented in the Java code, and if so, could not the hacker just GRANT himself more rights?

Comment: @HassanNazar The creation of users, and granting of permissions require different permission levels, which are not available to different users. So unless you give your program's DB user the permissions to either create other users, or to grant permissions, then they will not be able to do so. The commands to create users, or grant permissions is generally done through the mysql command line. Don't know of any method to check how a user was created though. Probably worthy of its own question in the mysql section.